# How to reference local class

Tags: java, local-class

I have a local class...

```
public class Outer {
    public void wrapper() {
        class Local {
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a test that needs to reference the local class...

```
Outer.wrapper.Local.class ## this doesn't seem to work
```

How can I reference the local class?

Comment: Just don't declare classes inside functions.

Comment: You can't. The class only exists within the scope of the function.

Comment: local classes are what their name says: local. They *can't* be referred outside

Comment: It does not compile

Comment: You can't use access modifiers on local classes, so this doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have added the `public` to Local.

Comment: You must getting compile time error ?

Comment: @Lino "can't be used outside" is not quite true: you can, say, return an instance of the local class, and then do... Whatever. But you can't refer to that class by name.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's what I actually meant, sorry. Changed the comment to say refer

Comment: @Lino - From the standpoint of my service, the local class is fine.  I only need the extra access for unit testing.  I guess I have to make a compromise on my service design in order to support the test.

Comment: @nobar from the POV of your production service they may be fine; but from the POV of your production service *and* testing your production service, they are not. You need to design for testability.

Comment: Why would a test need access to that class?  This sounds similar to attempting to directly test a private method.  IOW, test the behavior not the implementation.

Comment: @AndrewS: Point taken.  In this case, I was refactoring code against an existing set of tests.  I had moved the "Local" class from another location in an effort to improve functional cohesion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only reference a Local Inner class inside the method in which you have declared it:

```
public void wrapper() {
  class Local {

  }
  Local obj = new Local();
}
```

This classes tend to not be very useful due to their limited scope. If you have found a valid use case to define one take a look [at this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/local-inner-class).

Comment: So local classes are *implicitly* `private`.

Comment: @nobar *JLS 14.3. Local Class Declarations* prohibits modifiers so writing `private class Local` would trigger a compilation error. I'd say they are their own special bread.

Comment: @nobar no, they are local: they are as accessible as local variables (private classes are accessible, for example, in the same compilation unit). If you want to give it a label, that might be "really really private".

Comment: According to [JLS 14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3) "_Every local class declaration statement is immediately contained by a block_". Using this wording I would say they are _block private_. But "really really private" sounds better :)

Comment: *block private* is what I had in mind -- or private to the enclosing scope, which is the block.

Answer (score 0):

**Local Class** (a.k.a. Local Inner Class or Method-Local Inner Class):

Local class is defined as an inner class within a method. Like local variables, a local inner class declaration does not exist until the method is invoked, and it goes out of scope when the method returns. This means its instance can be created only from within the method it is declared in.

This inner class can be instantiated only after its definition (i.e., the instantiation code must follow the declaration). The inner class do not have access to local variables of the method unless those variables are final or effectively final.

Here is an example:

```
int length = 10; // outer class's instance variable

public void calculate() {
    final int width = 20;
    class Inner { // inner class definition
        public void area() {
            System.out.println(length * width);
        }
    }
    Inner local = new Inner(); // this statement comes only after local class's definition
    local.area();
}
```

**NOTES:**

- The only modifiers that can be applied to a method-local inner class
  are abstract and final, but never both at the same time.
- A local class declared within a static method has access to only static members of the enclosing class, and no access to instance
  variables.

Comment: This reads like copy&pasted from some tutorial, and it does not even answer the question of how to access that local class from outside the method.

Comment: The answer post content is _not_ from a tutorial. It is from my own notes which I had prepared for my Java SE 8 certification exam, sometime last year. I used it to get thru my exam. The answer shows how to use the method local class properly and some points to consider. The OP has the question as _How can I reference the local class?_ And, the post's title says _How to reference local class_.

Comment: I was specifically interested in referencing the local class from a separate test class.  Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: @nobar One can reference an inner class from another class; but not  a method local class. There are other (not local) type of inner classes to consider - regular inner class or a static nested class.

Comment: @nobar Here is the link to the Oracle's Java tutorials topic [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). This has detailed info about Nested classes in general and specifically of each type.